# divisors on $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ that are trivial on certain $F$-curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, algebraic-curves, divisors, picard-group

Inside the moduli space of curves $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,n}$ one can distinguish two classes of $F$-curves isomorphic to $\mathbb{P}^1$: those of type $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,4}$, and those of type $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}$. Are there divisor classes that are trivial once restricted to one or the other (or both) types of $F$-curves?

Comment: This is bad form -- I should really double-check this first.  However, my vague recollection is that inside $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{g,0}$, the following divisor class,
$$ D = \sum_{h=1}^{[g/2]} h(g-h) \Delta_h,$$
is zero on the $F$-curves of the form $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,4}$.  Clearly it is not zero on some of the $F$-curves of the form $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}$. I will try to double-check this.  If it is correct, then I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boundary divisor $\Delta_0$ has intersection number $0$ with every $F$-curve of the form $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,4}$, yet has nonzero intersection number with every $F$-curve of the form $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}$.

**Edit.**  Also, since $\lambda$ is the pullback of a divisor class from the Satake compactification of $\mathcal{A}_g$, also $\lambda$ has intersection number $0$ with every $F$-curve of the form $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{0,4}$, yet has nonzero intersection number with every $F$-curve of the form $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_{1,1}$.